# Finding the smallest Lipschitz constant of a function

Tags: real-analysis

Given:
\begin{align*}
& B:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \|x\|_{\infty}\leq1\} \\
& f: (B,\|.\|_{\infty}) \to (\mathbb{R}^2,\|.\|_{\infty})\,:\, [x,y]^T \mapsto [x^2-2y+1,y^2-x+2]^T
\end{align*}
I have already shown, that:
\begin{align*}
\|f([x,y]^T)-f([a,b]^T)\|_{\infty}\leq4\cdot\|[x,y]^T-[a,b]^T\|_{\infty}
\end{align*}
holds for all $[x,y]^T,[a,b]^T \in B$.

But how do I find the smallest possible Lipschitz constant?

Comment: Make all your inequalities equalities.

Comment: Since for $x=y=-1$ and $a=b=1$ the inequality holds with equality, the constant $C=4$ is the tightest global Lipschitz constant.